# JQuery Search for part of span class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

If I have a span class called "`peanutty`", and "`peanuts`", can I do a search for "`peanut*`"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
$('span[class^="peanut"]')
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/YgKHN/)**

See jQuery's [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

Comment: What code would i use to scroll through each span, to locate each span sequentially on a large html page?

Comment: What do you mean by scroll through the spans?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what it is you're looking to do, but `.each()` will iterate over a group of elements you select.

Comment: What I ultimately hope to do is provide a large html text to the user, with spans inserted on keywords, then allow the user to click a button and have the html page scroll to each occurrence one by one.

Comment: Oh. Well if you're stuck on the scrolling part I'd suggest starting a new question with the details of what you want and what you've tried.

Comment: Ok I posted the new question, please feel free to assist - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566539/jquery-scroll-occurrences-containing-common-prefix-in-span-class-name

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at this http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp but what you are asking for is something like this `$("[class~='hello']")` which would be a contains selector meaning it would select any class containing the word "hello", while `$("[class^='hello']")` would select any class beginning with the word "hello".

Comment: Just a heads up: I'd stick with MDN vs w3schools. They have no affiliation with w3 and have kinda a bad rap around here. MDN is really good.